# Bubble Shuffle - Weighted Shuffle

Tags: python, list, algorithm, shuffle, bubble-sort

It's possible to conceive of a modification to bubble sort where the "swap" occurs randomly with probability `p`, rather than by performing a comparison. The result could be called a "bubble shuffle". Elements near the front would be likely to remain there, but have a chance to be shifted to the back of the list.

Modifying a bubble sort stolen from the internet you could come up with the following:

```py
import random

def bubble_shuffle(arr, p):
    arr = copy.copy(arr)
    n = len(arr) 
  
    # Traverse through all array elements 
    for i in range(n-1): 
    # range(n) also work but outer loop will repeat one time more than needed. 
  
        # Last i elements are already in place 
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
  
            # traverse the array from 0 to n-i-1 
            # Swap if random number [0, 1] is less than p
            if random.random() < p:
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
    return arr
```

This algorithm is order n-squared... but the probability of an element ending up in any particular spot should be computable ahead of time, so it doesn't "need" to be n-squared.
Is there a more efficient approach which could be taken?

I'd considered sampling from a geometric distribution and add this to the original index (plus `(len(n)-i-1)/len(n)` to break ties), but this doesn't give the same dynamic.

Comment: There isn't any easy way to do better than `O(n^2)`.  I went a little bit down the rabbit hole and decided that if there was a way, I'm not smart enough to find it.

Comment: That's where I have landed. I'm sorry to have wasted your time, I hope you had fun.

Comment: Can you confirm whether for any (n,p) you're only looking to do 1 run or many? I.e., say for a given n & p there was O(n^2) work that needed to be done once regardless of the number of trials, but then each trial would be faster. Would that be interesting? Also, are approaches that have similar properties but aren't identical to bubble-shuffle interesting?

Comment: @Dave `bubble_suffle([1, 2, 3], 0.5)` shouldn't produce a deterministic output, unless you're setting a seed on the random number generation. Regarding similar properties, yes that would definitely be interesting and I think ultimately that's where the best answer for this question will lie, because I don't think a 'better' answer will show up, like your answer below. I'll review it in detail.

Comment: @poulter7 I know you don't want deterministic output. What I mean is, say for a given (p, n), if in O(n^2) time I could produce a probability matrix that could then be used to accurately simulate bubble_shuffle in linear time, would that be interesting. If you're going to be running bubble_shuffle(n, p) many times (more than O(n) times), or you have plenty of time to precompute probability matrices and only need the shuffle to be fast, then this is worthwhile.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. This is how I tested my original alternative implementations by producing a matrix of [item -> final_position], this allows you to match the result. 
Because of varied possibilities of `n`, each requiring some precomputation I think this approach would be impractical for my purposes. 
Though I imagine it would be a reasonable observation in some cases.

Comment: What are the min and max values of n & p that you'd like this for?

Comment: Ehmm... How can probabilities be computed in O(n^2)? I can see that having a probability vector for each element will have O(n^2) updates of the vectors, but they have n elements each so the trivial implementation would be O(n^3), right? And how could you use those probabilities, as the different elements are dependent?

Comment: @HansOlsson Right now I have code running to find vectors of p_values that give the same positional averages as bubble_shuffle using the simbub approach I described. This is expensive and only viable for relatively small n. I'm hoping to use these results to find a relationship between (n, p) and the associated probability vector.

Comment: In my particular usecase I could see a minimium of two and maximum of ~100 for n. For p it would be a constant and pre-determined, I'm thinking of starting at 0.5.

Comment: @poulter7 For 100 & 0.5, an inefficient language like ruby can generate over 1,100 bubble_shuffles per second on my machine, which is nothing special. What kind of speeds are you looking for, or is the hardware limited?

Comment: @HansOlsson E.g., in the simbub code I wrote, I notice that the probability to use in the n-k'th spot of the array is effectively identical except for k close to n. E.g., For n = [10, 15, 20], p=0.25, k=1, the associated probabilities are all 0.340. For k=2, I see [0.397, 0.395, 0.395], and for k=3 [0.437, 0.435, 0.434]. etc... As we get close to the start of the array, there are edge effects. How close depends on p. For p=0.5, it looks like we have noticable divergance about 7 away from the end.

Comment: @poulter7 If you scroll to the botton of my answer, I solved for the p_arr needed for n=100, p=0.5. Running both side-by-side this results in about a 7.7x speedup vs bubble shuffle with nearly average results in all positions. Call it a proof of concept. We could solve for the p_arrays needed for n=2-100, and some spacing of p-values, and interpolate correct p-values as needed.

Comment: Like a probability radix sort?

Answer (score 1):

With precomputation that only needs to be done once per (n, p), we can simulate bubble_shuffle runs in expected linear time (excluding precomputation).

Methods:
get_bub(n, p): O(n^2) method to run bubble_shuffle

get_expected_bub(n, p): O(n^2) method to calculate the expected average value in each position of running bubble_shuffle

get_dist(pos, p): O(1) method used by simbub that gets a random number of consecutive swaps based on the p being used.

get_simbub(n, p_arr): Expected O(n * min(n, (1/(1-p))) method to simulate running bubble_shuffle. For p = 0.5, this is expected O(n). For p = 1 - (1/n) this is O(n^2).

get_expected_simbub(n, p_arr): O(n^2) method to calculate the expected average value in each position of running simbub.

get_p_arr(n, p, tolerance): Method for seeking the p_arr that aligns simbub with bubble_shuffle (within tolerance) for a given n & p.

compare(n, p, p_arr, trials): Method to run simbub multiple times and compare the results to the expectation for bubble_shuffle.

time_trials(n, p, seconds): For a given n & p, run both bubble_shuffle and simbub for the input seconds and compare how many runs we're able to complete.

All code is in Ruby.

```
# Run bubble_shuffle
def get_bub(n, p)
  arr = [*0..(n-1)]
  0.upto(n-1) do |i|
    0.upto(n-i-2) do |j|
      if rand < p
        arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
      end
    end
  end
  return arr
end


# Get the expected average results of running bubble_shuffle many times
# This works by iteratively distributing value according to p.
def get_expected_bub(n, p)
  arr = [*0.upto(n-1)]  
  
  (n-1).downto(0) do |last_index|
    working_arr = arr.clone
    0.upto(last_index) do |i|
      working_arr[i] = 0
    end
    0.upto(last_index) do |source_index|

      min_sink = [0, source_index-1].max
      max_sink = last_index
      min_sink.upto(max_sink) do |sink_index|
        portion = 1.0
        if sink_index == source_index - 1
          portion *= p
        else
          portion *= (1-p) if source_index > 0
          portion *= (p**(sink_index - source_index)) if sink_index > source_index
          portion *= (1-p) if sink_index < last_index
        end
        working_arr[sink_index] += arr[source_index] * portion
      end

    end
    0.upto(last_index) do |i|
      arr[i] = working_arr[i]
    end
  end
  return arr
end


# For simbub, randomly get the distance to the index being swapped into 
# the current position
def get_dist(pos, p)
  return 0 if pos == 0
  return [pos, Math.log(1 - rand, p).floor].min
end


# Run simbub from the last-to-first index
# p_arr is the array of probabilities corresponding to the effective probability
# of swapping used at each position. The last value of this array will always
# equal the p value being simulated. So will the first, though this is not used.
def get_simbub(n, p_arr)
  arr = [*0..(n-1)]
  (n-1).downto(0) do |pos|
    p = p_arr[pos]
    dist = get_dist(pos, p)
    if dist > 0
      val_moving_up = arr[pos - dist]
      (pos - dist).upto(pos - 1) do |j|
        arr[j] = arr[j+1]
      end
      arr[pos] = val_moving_up
    end
  end
  return arr
end


# Get the expected average results of running simbub many times
# This works by iteratively distributing value according to p_arr.
def get_expected_simbub(n, p_arr)
  arr = [*0.upto(n-1)]  
  
  (n-1).downto(1) do |last_index|
    working_arr = arr.clone
    0.upto(last_index) do |i|
      working_arr[i] = 0
    end
    
    p = p_arr[last_index]
    cum_p_distance = 0
    0.upto(last_index) do |distance|

      if distance == last_index
        p_distance = p ** distance
      else
        p_distance = (1-p) * (p ** distance)
      end
      
      working_arr[last_index] += p_distance * arr[last_index - distance]
      
      if distance >= 1
        working_arr[last_index - distance] = arr[last_index - distance] + (1 - cum_p_distance) * (arr[last_index - distance + 1] - arr[last_index - distance])
      end
     
      cum_p_distance += p_distance
    end
    arr = working_arr
  end
  return arr
end


# Solve for the p_arr that yields the same expected averages for simbub for 
# each position (within tolerance) as bub
def get_p_arr(n, p, tolerance = 0.00001)
  expected_bub = get_expected_bub(n, p)
  p_arr = [p] * n
  
  (n-2).downto(1) do |pos|
    min_pos_p = 0.0
    max_pos_p = 1.0
    while true do
      expected_simbub = get_expected_simbub(n, p_arr)
      if expected_simbub[pos] > expected_bub[pos] + tolerance
        min_pos_p = p_arr[pos]
        p_arr[pos] = (p_arr[pos] + max_pos_p) / 2.0
      elsif expected_simbub[pos] < expected_bub[pos] - tolerance
        max_pos_p = p_arr[pos]
        p_arr[pos] = (p_arr[pos] + min_pos_p) / 2.0
      else
        break
      end
    end
  end
  return p_arr
end


def compare(n, p, p_arr, trials)
  expected_bub = get_expected_bub(n, p)
  #bub_totals = [0]*n
  simbub_totals = [0]*n
  trials.times do 
    simbub_trial = get_simbub(n, p_arr, 0)
    #bub_trial = bub(n, p)
    0.upto(n-1) do |i|
      simbub_totals[i] += simbub_trial[i] 
      #bub_totals[i] += bub_trial[i]
    end
  end

  puts "   #:  expbub |  simbub |   delta"

  0.upto(n-1) do |i|
    #b = bub_totals[i] / trials.to_f
    b = expected_bub[i]
    s = simbub_totals[i] / trials.to_f
    puts "#{(i).to_s.rjust(4)}: #{b.round(2).to_s.rjust(7)} | #{s.round(2).to_s.rjust(7)} | #{(s-b).round(2).to_s.rjust(7)}"
  end
end


def time_trials(n, p, seconds)
  t = Time.now
  bub_counter = 0
  while Time.now < t + seconds do
    get_bub(n, p)
    bub_counter += 1
  end
  t = Time.now
  p_arr = get_p_arr(n, p, 0.0001)
  p_arr_seconds = Time.now - t
  t = Time.now
  simbub_counter = 0
  while Time.now < t + seconds do
    get_simbub(n, p_arr)
    simbub_counter += 1
  end
  puts "Trial results (#{seconds} seconds): "
  puts "Time to get p_arr for simbub: #{p_arr_seconds.round(2)}"
  puts "bub runs: #{bub_counter}"
  puts "simbub runs: #{simbub_counter}"
  puts "ratio: #{(simbub_counter.to_f/bub_counter.to_f).round(2)}"
end
```

Errors vs expectation for n=100, p=0.5

```
compare(100, 0.5, p_arr, 10000)
   #:  expbub |  simbub |   delta
   0:   10.27 |   10.23 |   -0.04
   1:   10.27 |   10.18 |   -0.09
   2:   10.33 |   10.16 |   -0.16
   3:   10.44 |   10.45 |    0.01
   4:   10.61 |   10.66 |    0.05
   5:   10.83 |   10.83 |   -0.01
   6:   11.11 |    11.1 |   -0.02
   7:   11.45 |    11.5 |    0.05
   8:   11.84 |   11.92 |    0.08
   9:   12.27 |   12.35 |    0.08
  10:   12.76 |   12.78 |    0.02
  11:   13.29 |   13.23 |   -0.06
  12:   13.87 |   13.72 |   -0.15
  13:   14.49 |   14.58 |    0.09
  14:   15.15 |   15.14 |   -0.01
  15:   15.85 |   15.83 |   -0.02
  16:   16.58 |   16.51 |   -0.06
  17:   17.34 |   17.35 |    0.01
  18:   18.13 |   18.26 |    0.13
  19:   18.95 |    19.0 |    0.05
  20:   19.79 |   19.75 |   -0.04
  21:   20.66 |   20.85 |    0.19
  22:   21.54 |    21.7 |    0.16
  23:   22.45 |   22.64 |    0.19
  24:   23.36 |   23.49 |    0.13
  25:   24.29 |   24.19 |   -0.11
  26:   25.24 |   25.17 |   -0.07
  27:   26.19 |   26.38 |    0.19
  28:   27.15 |   27.16 |    0.01
  29:   28.12 |   28.16 |    0.05
  30:   29.09 |   28.99 |    -0.1
  31:   30.07 |   30.08 |     0.0
  32:   31.05 |   31.19 |    0.14
  33:   32.04 |   31.88 |   -0.16
  34:   33.03 |   33.07 |    0.03
  35:   34.02 |   33.78 |   -0.24
  36:   35.02 |   34.97 |   -0.05
  37:   36.01 |   36.05 |    0.04
  38:   37.01 |    37.0 |   -0.01
  39:   38.01 |   37.95 |   -0.06
  40:    39.0 |   38.94 |   -0.07
  41:    40.0 |   39.94 |   -0.06
  42:    41.0 |   41.01 |     0.0
  43:    42.0 |   42.08 |    0.08
  44:    43.0 |   42.87 |   -0.13
  45:    44.0 |   43.88 |   -0.12
  46:    45.0 |   44.99 |   -0.02
  47:    46.0 |   45.92 |   -0.08
  48:    47.0 |    46.8 |    -0.2
  49:    48.0 |   47.92 |   -0.08
  50:    49.0 |   49.01 |    0.01
  51:    50.0 |   50.04 |    0.04
  52:    51.0 |   51.11 |    0.11
  53:    52.0 |   51.95 |   -0.05
  54:    53.0 |   53.08 |    0.08
  55:    54.0 |   54.05 |    0.05
  56:    55.0 |   54.95 |   -0.05
  57:    56.0 |   55.98 |   -0.02
  58:    57.0 |   57.13 |    0.13
  59:    58.0 |   58.01 |    0.01
  60:    59.0 |   59.11 |    0.11
  61:    60.0 |   60.01 |    0.01
  62:    61.0 |   61.02 |    0.02
  63:    62.0 |   61.93 |   -0.07
  64:    63.0 |   63.05 |    0.05
  65:    64.0 |   64.01 |    0.01
  66:    65.0 |    65.0 |    -0.0
  67:    66.0 |   66.04 |    0.04
  68:    67.0 |   67.11 |    0.11
  69:    68.0 |   68.01 |    0.01
  70:    69.0 |   69.03 |    0.03
  71:    70.0 |   70.08 |    0.08
  72:    71.0 |   70.96 |   -0.04
  73:    72.0 |   72.01 |    0.01
  74:    73.0 |   72.95 |   -0.05
  75:    74.0 |    74.0 |    -0.0
  76:    75.0 |   74.99 |   -0.01
  77:    76.0 |   75.92 |   -0.08
  78:    77.0 |   76.98 |   -0.02
  79:    78.0 |   77.91 |   -0.09
  80:    79.0 |   79.05 |    0.05
  81:    80.0 |   79.96 |   -0.04
  82:    81.0 |    81.0 |    -0.0
  83:    82.0 |    82.0 |    -0.0
  84:    83.0 |   82.98 |   -0.02
  85:    84.0 |   84.06 |    0.06
  86:    85.0 |   84.99 |   -0.01
  87:    86.0 |   85.97 |   -0.03
  88:    87.0 |    87.0 |    -0.0
  89:    88.0 |   88.04 |    0.04
  90:    89.0 |   88.95 |   -0.05
  91:    90.0 |   90.03 |    0.03
  92:    91.0 |   91.01 |    0.01
  93:    92.0 |   91.97 |   -0.03
  94:    93.0 |   92.98 |   -0.02
  95:    94.0 |   94.01 |    0.01
  96:    95.0 |   94.99 |   -0.01
  97:    96.0 |   95.97 |   -0.03
  98:    97.0 |   97.03 |    0.03
  99:    98.0 |    98.0 |    -0.0
```

Time Trials: (simbub runs in 60s) / (bubble_shuffle runs in 60s)

```
         p=0.01  p=0.25  p=0.50  p=0.75  p=0.99
n = 100   10.85   10.17   10.75    9.53    4.16
n = 200   22.98   18.11   17.30   13.46    5.33 
n = 300   27.70   25.03   23.88   18.11    5.94
n = 400   41.09   29.46   27.11   21.81    6.92
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with btilly and others that the correlations make this very difficult if not impossible to do exactly.

Regarding your approach, it's true that the motion for a single pass is sort of geometrically distributed. For many passes, however, the Central Limit Theorem starts to kick in. Ignoring boundary effects, in a single pass, an element moves left once with probability `p`, and otherwise (with probability `(1-p)`) moves right a geometric number of times with success probability `1-p`. The mean of this distribution is zero. The first possibility contributes `p (-1)^2 = p` to the variance. The second contributes `(1-p) sum_{i>=0} p^i (1-p) i^2`, which Wolfram Alpha evaluates as `(1+p) p / (1-p)`.

Letting this variance be `v = p + (1+p) p / (1-p)`, we can imagine that the delta position of an element after `t` passes is distributed normally with mean zero and standard deviation `sqrt(t v)`. Our next approximations are to switch from discrete to continuous time and, for each element, to pull a normal sample `x` and assume that the delta position changes smoothly as `sqrt(t v) x`. For an element originally in position `i`, we can solve the equation `i + sqrt(t v) x = n - t` for `t` to approximate when that element was locked. Then we just sort by those `t` descending.

Here's a short Python program implementing this. Hopefully it gets close enough.

```
import math
import random


def variance(p):
    return p + (1 + p) * p / (1 - p)


def solve_quadratic(b, c):
    assert c < 0
    return (math.sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * c) - b) / 2


def bubble_shuffle(arr, p):
    n = len(arr)
    s = math.sqrt(variance(p))
    return [
        arr[i]
        for i in sorted(
            range(n),
            key=lambda i: solve_quadratic(random.gauss(0, s), i - n),
            reverse=True,
        )
    ]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(bubble_shuffle(range(100), 0.5))
```

Comment: To quantify boundary effects, for n=100, p=0.5, This gives an average of 6.42 vs expected 10.27 at index 0, and 98.26 vs 98.0 at index 99.

Comment: Any thoughts on "How to shuffle array of items but allow weights to influence the order"? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/q/77337410/470749