# How to shuffle array of items but allow weights to influence the order

Tags: arrays, typescript, random, shuffle, fisher-yates-shuffle

I'm trying to write a TypeScript function to shuffle an array.

By default, I want the shuffle order to be random (but subject to a seed).
(I already have access to this function: `function random(seed: number): number`)

However, I want to also allow influencing the order via weights per item.

In other words, I want the the default item weight to be 1, and if an item has a weight of 10, it should be 10 times more likely to appear sooner in the shuffled order.

Am I even thinking about this correctly? Is this a reasonable goal?

I was thinking that I'd need to use the Fisher-Yates algorithm but adapted to honor a weights array of the same length as the main array, and the main array will be shuffled such that higher weighted items are more likely to appear first.

```
function removeDuplicates<T>(array: T[]): T[] {
  const uniqueValues = new Set<T>();
  return array.filter((item) => {
    if (!uniqueValues.has(item)) {
      uniqueValues.add(item);
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });
}

function duplicateItemsBasedOnWeights<T>(array: T[], weights: number[]): T[] {
  const result = [];
  for (const [index, element] of array.entries()) {
    for (let position = 0; position < weights[index]; position++) {
      result.push(element);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

export function shuffleWithWeights<T>(array: T[], weights: number[], seed: number): T[] {
  const arrayWithDuplicateValuesBasedOnWeights: T[] = duplicateItemsBasedOnWeights(array, weights);

  const shuffledArrayWithDuplicateValuesBasedOnWeights = shuffleArrayUsingFisherYates(arrayWithDuplicateValuesBasedOnWeights, seed);

  return removeDuplicates(shuffledArrayWithDuplicateValuesBasedOnWeights);
}
```

I've looked at empirical results by calling it a bunch of different times with these values (and a different seed each time), and the results don't seem distributed how I'd hoped, so I must have been approaching this problem incorrectly.

```
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const weights = [1, 1, 1, 200, 1_000];
```

In my real-world cases, I'll be shuffling 70,000 objects (which would explore to *many* more than that if I use my current approach of creating duplicate items based on item weight).

Comment: @OrangeBunny That is Python...

Comment: Out and about, but since you pinged: generate an exponential random variate for each item, with lambda = the rate of that item. Sort.

Comment: Sorry, rate = weight (log uniform / weight, where uniform is a random variate in (0, 1). Watch out for divide by zero.)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqq9km) meet your needs (I feel like the random number seed is out of scope here, since you can just modify the `Math.random()` to use whatever algorithm you want)? If so I could expand it into an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz there is known algo I put reference below, could send paper if you need it

Comment: Me?  I’m not the one asking the question

Comment: @jcalz Wow!! That is amazing!  Yes, I do think that's what I'm looking for. So, how would you describe it? Is that using the Fisher-Yates algorithm at all, or `Weighted Random Sampling, Efraimidis, Spirakis 2005` or something else? In my comment in my repo, I want to link to your answer once you post it and want to describe in general terms what it's doing and if it's inspired by any known algorithm in particular. Thanks so much for this. It's a huge help.

Comment: @jcalz I am trying to share the TS playground URL of what I have so far, but the URL is getting blocked because of length, and then I tried to use Bitly to shorten, but StackOverflow blocked that too. How did you shorten yours?

Comment: My url is from https://tsplay.dev/.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you! Here is what I have: https://tsplay.dev/mAPJ8N

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that the objects in your arrays will have a numeric `weight` property which you can use to determine the weight, and a `value` property to hold the data you care about.  So the array is of type `Array<{value: unknown, weight: number}>`.  I am also just going to use `Math.random()` to generate a uniformly chosen random number between `0` (inclusive) and `1` (exclusive).  If you have objects in a different format, or a custom random number generator that takes a seed, you can adjust the answer below to accommodate that.  I consider these out of scope here, especially since your `random(seed)` function isn't available for others to use and isn't specified enough for an answer to use it (e.g., is it uniform between `0` and `1` like `Math.random()`?  If you call `random()` with the same seed twice do you get two different answers or does the seed need to evolve also?  etc).

Also note, the implementation below does not necessarily have optimal time complexity.  It is O(n<sup>2</sup>) because `weightedIndexChoice()` is O(n) and `weightedShuffle()` calls it n times.  If optimal time complexity is important there are apparently other solutions which will do so in O(n log n), which is better.  The other answer below shows how to do it in python, and presumably someone can come up with a JS/TS implementation and post that here.

---

The [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is basically just building up a new array by randomly picking (and removing) elements from the first array, and pushing them onto the new array.  There are various ways to implement that.  The following does it by walking from the start to the end of the array and swapping a random element from later in the array to the current position:

```
function weightedShuffle(arr: { value: unknown, weight: number }[]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const v = weightedIndexChoice(arr.slice(i));
        [arr[i + v], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[i + v]];
    }
}
```

The important part of the above for your question is `weightedIndexChoice()`, which needs to randomly select an index of an array, weighted by the `weight`.  Note that since you say you want more heavily weighted elements to be more likely to appear at the *start* of the array, that means we need to put the first randomly selected element at the start of the array.  Some implementations of Fisher-Yates do it from the end of the array, and for uniformly random selections it doesn't matter. But if we did that without changing the weights it would end up putting more heavily weighted elements at the end, which isn't what you want.

There are definitely existing Stack Overflow question/answers covering how to implement `weightedIndexChoice()`.  For example, [How to choose a weighted random array element in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43566019/2887218).  Here's one way:

```
function weightedIndexChoice(arr: { value: unknown, weight: number }[]): number {
    const totalWeight = arr.map(v => v.weight).reduce((x, y) => x + y);
    const val = Math.random() * totalWeight;
    for (let i = 0, cur = 0; ; i++) {
        cur += arr[i].weight;
        if (val <= cur) return i;
    }
}
```

Essentially you choose a random number uniformly between `0` and the total of the weights.  Then you figure out which element index corresponds to that number by taking the cumulative sum of the weights of the elements until you pass the random number.  As a simple example, let's imagine you have three elements: `[{value: "a", weight: 1}, {value: "b", weight: 2}, {value: "c", weight: 3}]`.  The total weight is `6`.  So you pick a random number between `0` (inclusive) and `6` (exclusive).  The cumulative sum of the weights are `1` for `"a"`; `1+2`=`3` for `"b"`; and `1+2+3`=`6` for `"c"`.  So if your random number is between `0` and `1` you choose `"a"`, if it's between `1` and `3` you choose `"b"`, and if it's between `3` and `6` you choose `"c"`.  You can see that the chance of choosing each element is proportional to its weight.

---

I'm not sure the best way to test this, but starting with your example

```
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const weights = [1, 1, 1, 200, 1_000];
```

we can build an array of the form accepted above:

```
const arr = items.map((value, i) => ({ value, weight: weights[i] }));
```

run the shuffle a bunch of times and keep track of the results:

```
const results: number[][] = [];
const numTrials = 100_000;
for (let i = 0; i < numTrials; i++) {
    weightedShuffle(arr);
    results.push(arr.slice().map(v => v.value))
}
```

and then... well, the easiest thing to check is the relative weighting of the first element of the array for each result, since that should be exactly proportional to your weights:

```
const firstPos: Record<number, number> = {};
items.forEach(v => firstPos[v] = 0);
results.forEach(vals => firstPos[vals[0]] = (firstPos[vals[0]] ?? 0) + 1);
const totalWeight = weights.reduce((x, y) => x + y);

// this is the weighted occurrence of the first element of the shuffled array
console.log(Object.entries(firstPos).map(([k, v]) => [k, v * totalWeight / numTrials]));
// [["1", 0.93834], ["2", 0.98646], ["3", 1.02255], ["4", 199.20477], ["5", 1000.84788]]
```

The actual logged results will depend on the random numbers chosen, but this is promising.

After this you *could* start checking the second element for each result conditional on the fact that the first element is not available, and show that the results are as expected.  But frankly all we're doing is reverse engineering the Fisher-Yates shuffle and making sure the weighted index choice is in keeping with our expectations.  Not sure it's worth doing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-jF0M4diCqB2I3aRXBjOIZJ2EB8euE0z6fT6tMhpTKAAqTBg-HD0ZT8fKlMe1MQczWdIZw7HE74dg5u045OrUNh8MRkpYSv37c79YCIRAdiwyMCMrliWCYX50W4ASLqEVgPM6bVI4wAwEwDgAApwHY7AAEqoLYTB4M8w6mDIKEaNEvgcFo5Q5qgjoBJSACiDAQA+H5jKBEFQTomoLOel5dnmxGkeRk55CBYFQJBDbog2qZ6r4dCcdRvGTjoAmIAA-FJiDzLkxTOueIbOK4fAeJC9R1nmyR4Kk9AZNkuTeNEBTFGUAEAPSWU4WAwE69m2agB74IgcAQEcySQM5cAPC0zkiY4qDTMoqBgI4vlOYg97HtMeAmgwWSAXYcDTMycAYHQADyqgAFbwVAARhVA46oHYwlUdxUGvgWdA6CIMiasZ0T1Y1iB9KpgyaTZ67jpOhjntZiA6DoABEzqjTIzoBHGnrGmNbqTXJAQAJwAGxuj682jZ6S3TWtAAcPputtPpLXG03zG6zpzTIY3+ktK0rQdATOm6K3OrqiAAUAA)

Comment: Wow!  This is unbelievably thoughtful and helpful. I REALLY appreciate it. Out of appreciation, I will award a bounty when the site allows me to. Thanks! ❤️

Comment: Presumably it’s the other answerer, who doesn’t like the time complexity of my answer. I don’t see optimal time complexity as a requirement for the question so I’m not too concerned about making a change or retraction, but if someone thinks this answer is bad because of it then it’s their prerogative to downvote.

Comment: @jcalz That was me, unhappy with development. Bumping it back

Comment: @jcalz I tried this in my app this morning and wonder if it's not actually shuffling correctly. For example, even when I set all weights to `1` (and expect the items therefore to be randomly shuffled), I see items in an order that is barely shuffled:  `…6492,6493,6494,6495,519,6496,6497,6498,6499,524,6500,…` I wonder if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I will go back to your playground link and add more demonstrations there to better understand since I bet I just pulled it into my app incorrectly.

Comment: Doing equal weights on the array of 5 and comparing the frequency of each permutation to its expected frequency yields pretty reasonable results as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mLr3Aw).  A million shuffles and each of the 120 permutations shows up between 97% and 102% as often as expected.  I'd be surprised if things are as bad as your example shows.  ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz I think you're right. My experiment at https://tsplay.dev/Wo1YeN seems to look good. I need to speed it up so that it can handle ~100k items in just a few seconds. I'll see what I can do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Weighted Random Sampling, Efraimidis, Spirakis 2005

Link to paper: [https://utopia.duth.gr/~pefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf](https://utopia.duth.gr/%7Epefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf)

UPDATE

Don't have Javascript skills, but paper above provided OPTIMAL algorithm for such shuffle. What is accepted as an answer is O(n<sup>2</sup>), which will show up on large data.

Efraimidis&Spirakis is O(n log(n)), basically sorting complexity.

People, READ PAPERS and don't invent wheels.

WRS algorithm, Python 3.10, Windows x64

```
import numpy as np

items = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
freqs = np.array([1., 1., 1., 200., 1000.0])

wghts = freqs / np.sum(freqs)
print(wghts)

rng = np.random.default_rng(1357907531)

counter = np.zeros(len(items))

N = 1000000

for k in range(0, N):
    u01 = rng.random(len(items))
    ki  = np.power( u01 , 1.0/wghts)
    q = np.argsort(ki)
    
    counter[q[-1]] += 1

print(counter/np.sum(counter))
```

and it prints for normalized weights

```
[0.00083126 0.00083126 0.00083126 0.16625104 0.8312552]
```

and for sampling tests

```
[8.36000e-04 8.19000e-04 8.55000e-04 1.65964e-01 8.31526e-01]
```

Beautiful algorithm, applicable to streaming, reservoir style sampling, **m** from **n** sampling you name it.

UPDATE II

Here is another link to WRS implementations in Java, different variations of it, done by Efraimidis.

[https://utopia.duth.gr/~pefraimi/projects/WRS/](https://utopia.duth.gr/%7Epefraimi/projects/WRS/)

Quick complexity analysis

There is one pass which generate **n** random numbers, timing n*T<sub>RNG</sub>, O(n)

There is another pass where we compute u01 to the power of inverse weight, power being done by log&exp calls n*(T<sub>log</sub>+T<sub>exp</sub>), O(n)

If loops are done manually, not by some vectorized library like numpy, they could be combined.

Last step is sorting, which is O(n log(n)), and for large **n** this term would dominate, making WRS algorithm complexity O(n log(n))

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer and think others in the future will too. When you mentioned that paper yesterday, I searched for that paper and started to read it, but it's way over my head. It would take me more time than it's worth to try to understand. I don't have a PhD in math or computer science and have a mere mortal brain.  "Weighted Random Sampling" doesn't even _sound_ like shuffling to me, and I wouldn't have thought to give that paper a try except that you made the connection. +1 from me. Thanks so much for this discussion!

Comment: Someone might want to edit this with a JS version and then (assuming this works as advertised) this should be the accepted solution.

Comment: @Ryan  "Weighted Random Sampling" doesn't even sound like shuffling to me. Well, they were solving more generic "select without replacement m samples out of n weighted objects". But when m==n this is exactly a shuffling procedure. I'm adding another update on complexity etc.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, I agree, that would be nice to have as reference implementation, if original author could make it I would happy to endorse it. Apologies for emotional outburst

Comment: Possibly [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WKrpZm) does the same thing?  It's hard for me to be 100% sure but it looks right.

Comment: @jcalz I didn't see your comment from an hour ago til now. Here is my new version, using colors in the logs to get a sense for how shuffled it is. E.g. `["⚪", "", "⚫", "", "A", "", "", "", "", "B"]` https://tsplay.dev/mbyEbN So then if I use weights `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9]` I'd expect the final color in the original array to often be the first color in the shuffled array, with the rest of the colors completely random. I _think_ it's working.

Comment: Except now that I try a single iteration where the number of items is 70k (or even 10k), it hangs/crashes, so I'll investigate performance issues since I won't be able to use it unless I can make it run in < 4 seconds. https://tsplay.dev/mAPJXN

Comment: @Ryan it is hard for me to judge TS/JS version, but 1/weight[i] could be (and should be) precomputed once before as something like inverse_weight[i]=1/weight[i]. Also, I don't know how power function is implemented in TS/JS, so might be worthwhile to do explicitely exp(log(u[i])*inverse_weight[i]). Also if U01 is in the range [0...1) use 1.-u[i] instead to avoid log(0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but I wrote this a while ago (C# implementation): https://github.com/cdanek/KaimiraWeightedList

It seems as if there's a continued need for this in javascript and python, but I haven't really had time to port mine over. I'll try to do that soon.

This should get you started, though (on an O(1) time and space-complexity algorithm).

Comment: Link-only answers are not valid answers. Nobody should need to visit your GitHub project to understand what the answer is.